# How to apply charset to Redis ConnectionPool?

Tags: python, redis

Have problems with charset (want to work with strings, not bytes) with Redis Connection Pool.

If I'm connecting to Redis like this:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
r.set('foo', ['eggs', 'spam'])
r.set('awa', 'ororor')
print(r)
print(r['foo'])
print(r['awa'])
```

Everything is OK:

```
StrictRedis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
['eggs', 'spam']
ororor
```

But, if I try to use ConnectionPool:

```
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=pool, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
r.set('foo', ['eggs', 'spam'])
r.set('awa', 'ororor')
print(r)
print(r['foo'])
print(r['awa'])
```

I get bytes:

```
StrictRedis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
b"['eggs', 'spam']"
b'ororor'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe..
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=pool, charset="utf-8")

Comment: Please add more context to the answer, and format it so it's easier to read.